# Find Tuesday of the week based on the date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to show Tuesday of the week based on the date entered using SQL.

For example:
Date: 07-11-2014
Week: 07-11-2014 is in the week from 07-06-2014 to 07-12-2014
So Tuesday of the week is: 07-08-2014

What I want is find Tuesday of the week that mm-dd-yyyy is in.

How to do this?

Thank you!

p.s. I'm using sql server

Comment: Were you able to find an answer here?  Please consider checking the  mark below the voting arrows if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,'07-11-2014'), 1)
```

This works by selecting the first day of the week. `DATEDIFF(ww,0,'07-11-2014')` then adding 1 to that day. `DATEADD(ww,..., 1)`

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/35731)